# Recording overall time of nested stream processing in reactive Java

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am refactoring reactive code that logs elapsed time by using `collectList` on Mongo `saveAll` function, along with `elapsed` to get total elapsed time of the set of operations. I have refactored out the usage of `collectList` as well as now using `save` instead `collectList` and `saveAll`, however I am having difficulty with where to collect the elapsed time.

Code:

```
personRepo
  .findAll()
  .parallel()
  .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
  .map(person-> {
    person.setProcessed(true)
    return person;
  })
  .subscribe(mappedPerson-> {
    personRepo.save(mappedPerson)
      .map(personToProcess-> new ProcessedPersonReport(personToProcess))
      .map(processReport-> {
        try {
          processReport.setResults(processReport.getPersonToProcess())
        } catch (Exception e) {
          log.error("Can't process person", e);
        }
        return c;
      })
      .subscribe(processedReport-> {
        personProcessRepo.save(processedReport)
        .subscribe();
      });
});
```

When I use `elapsed`, I am able to retreive the tuple for invidual DB interactions, but I would like to collect all of these into a single elapsed time to help optimize my code here and within the `getPersonToProcess` function.

Comment: I dont see any `elapsed` Or any time measurments in the code provided.

Comment: I've tried various places, however in the absence of a collected mono, they all reported elapsed time of a single item from the stream.

Comment: well first of all you need to remove all subscribes, the calling client is the subscriber, your application is a producer, the calling client is the consumer, and the consumer subscribes to the producer. Then start using flatMap, instead of map (read up on the difference) and lastly dont use try catch, we dont use try catch in reactive programming, we use Mono.error. All i have mentioned now is basics of reactor. You should really read up on the basics of reactor, because you wont understand the answer given to you unless you know the basics.

Comment: also parallel should be removed, you have no use for parallel here, especially when you use map, parallel will most likely not give you any gain.

Comment: Thanks, however the subscriber is not a client. This is a nightly chron job.

Comment: Well since that is not mentioned you get what answer you get. We are not mind readers

Comment: Then you should then remove all subscribes but one